# An unknown software opens a window that can't be closed even from the Task Manager

Tags: windows-7, process, kill, tasks

There is a windows that keeps on reappearing on my desktop and won't go away (it's not listed in the Application or Processes tab of Task Manager). It looks like a plain light gray box with two 'Caption' written. It looks like this:

[image]

And it stays on top of all other windows so it's really annoying. I wonder if RegClean Pro has something to do with this (I did not install the software/malware, maybe installed by some third-party I-don't-know-what) but I can't uninstall it because it doesn't appear in Programs and Features and there is no Uninstall option in the folder in Start > All Programs > RegClean Pro folder.

And lastly, my Tab and Caps Lock key don't work (Asus Eee PC), I don't know if all these issues are related but maybe you can help me with these? I wonder if I am the only one who experiences this. Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Download either [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), and use their "Find window owner" feature.

Comment: You can create a screenshot, upload it at http://imgur.com/ and then just add the URL to your post. Someone with more reputation will replace the standard link with an image link.

Comment: Can you recommend a safe software that can help me identify which programs/software are malware or not, if they are safe to remove or if they are just bloatwares? Oh, and by the way, I already edited my post to include the link above.

Comment: Just do what @grawity said: Use Process Explorer and identify the process. There is absolutely no way this wouldn’t work.

Comment: You don't need such programs as RegClean Pro. Also be sure to run as a Standard user and not Administrator User. As other already said try Process Hacker.

Comment: I'll get back to you guys when the 'mysterious' window reappears. Because I tried to do a 'selective startup' (or something like that, the one set up from msconfig), the window does not appear anymore (I already did this 1 or 2 months ago, I think, and I believed that the window will go away forever, but ta-da, it was here again just earlier). So, I think I'll have to wait for sometime again to see if it will reappear, and if it will, I will try Process Hacker/Process Explorer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use:

- **Malwarebytes Anti-Malware** ~ https://www.malwarebytes.org/
- **ESET Online Scanner** ~ http://www.eset.com/int/home/products/online-scanner/

P.S.: If you don't trust *MBAM*, you can use **Spybot: Search & Destroy** ~ http://www.safer-networking.org/

Software above has one of the highest success rate.